# JavaScript - Dynamic div tag closes automatically before insertion of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, conditional-statements

Im using JavaScript to dynamically add HTML based on certain conditions. I want to place the HTML inside a duplicated div tag that is created when I press a button (onClick).

```
div = document.getElementById('userNumbers');

div.append('<div class="numbers">')
    for (n = 1; n < 81; n++) {
        if (n < 10) {
            //etc
            div.append('<div class="nums"><p>' + n + '</p></div>');

        } else {
            //etc
            div.append('<div class="nums"><p>' + n + '</p></div>'); 
        }
    }
div.append('</div>');
```

As you can see, all I want to do is wrap the HTML inside of a div called 'numbers', what is happening though is that the div I open called numbers instantly closes. and the HTML can't go inside it. I have a rough understanding of why this is happening.

[image]

Is there a work around for this problem? I have tried doing the "document.createElement('div')" solution but that brings up a whole set of other problems.

Long story short, I just want to open the div, add the code based on conditions, and close it.

Comment: Why not give your new div with the class numbers an ID? Then you can use `appendChild()`  in your for loop?

Comment: is there an `append` in javascript ?

Comment: every time you press the button a new 'numbers' div with all the html inside is created. When I read the page code in my browser, ( and collapsed) I want it to read "numbers, numbers, numbers,etc"

@Mritunjay , yes there is append functionality (with DOM).

Comment: It looks like you're mixing standard Javascript and jQuery. `append` is a jQuery method, it can't be applied to a DOM element.

Comment: What is `div.append`? DOM nodes do not normally have an `append` method. Are you using jQuery somewhere?

Comment: I was originally going to use ".write" but that clears the page so I thought using ".append" would add to it.

Comment: DOM elements are not the same as HTML code. There are no opening and closing elements in the DOM, those are just how it's represented in HTML. In the DOM, there's just a single node representing the DIV -- it can't be unclosed.

Comment: @Barmar , ok, what is the correct way to open/close a div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't append an unclosed element to the DOM. DOM elements are nodes in a tree, not the same as the HTML text that represents it in files.

What you should do is set a variable to the `numbers` DIV, and append to that.

```
div = $("#userNumbers");
numbers = $('<div class="numbers">').appendTo(div);
for (n = 1; n < 81; n++) {
    if (n < 10) {
        //etc
        numbers.append('<div class="nums"><p>' + n + '</p></div>');

    } else {
        //etc
        numbers.append('<div class="nums"><p>' + n + '</p></div>'); 
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could do all your appending using HTML strings, and then finally insert that HTML:

```
div = document.getElementById('userNumbers');
html = '<div class="numbers">';
for (n = 1; n < 81; n++) {
    if (n < 10) {
        //etc
        html += '<div class="nums"><p>' + n + '</p></div>';

    } else {
        //etc
        html += '<div class="nums"><p>' + n + '</p></div>';
    }
}
div.innerHTML += html;
```

Comment: I understand now!! Thanks so much, your first solution works best for what I need to do. I now understand the use of DOM too :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var div = document.getElementById("userNumbers");
    var append = "<div class='numbers'>"
    for (i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
        if (i < 10) {
            append += "<div class='nums'>First if:" + i + "</div>";
        }else{
            append += "<div class='nums'>Second if" + i + "</div>";
        }
    }
    append += "</div>";
    div.innerHTML = append;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some great answers but if you want to create the element rather than write it as innerHTML here's a quick run through.

**Create:**
 `document.createElement('ElementType')` Element type can be any html element `div`,`p`,`span`,`img`

**Attributes:** `.setAttribute('Attribute', 'Property');` Attributes can be any html attribute. Example: `id`,`class`,`onclick`

**Append:** `.appendChild()` self explanatory

---

```
var Target= document.getElementById('Container');
var NewElement= document.createElement('div');
NewElement.setAttribute('id', 'Content');
NewElement.setAttribute('class', 'Something');
NewElement.setAttribute('onclick', 'MyFunction();');
Target.appendChild(NewElement);
```

**Answer to your question**

```js
function Numbers(){
var numbersdiv = document.getElementById('userNumbers');
// If Div Element Numbers Does not Exist Build It
if(!document.getElementById('numbers')){
var numberselement = document.createElement('div');
    numberselement.setAttribute('id', 'numbers');
    numberselement.setAttribute('class', 'numbers');
    numbersdiv.appendChild(numberselement);
}
var InsertTo=document.getElementById('numbers');
for (n = 1; n < 81; n++) {
// Why the if condition? Both true/false have the same output
if (n < 10) {
    //etc
var Nums = document.createElement('div');
    Nums.setAttribute('class', 'nums');
    Nums.innerHTML='<p>' + n + '</p>';
    InsertTo.appendChild(Nums);
}else{
    //etc
var Nums = document.createElement('div');
    Nums.setAttribute('class', 'nums');
    Nums.innerHTML='<p>' + n + '</p>';
    InsertTo.appendChild(Nums);
}}}
```

```html
<button onclick="Numbers()">Create Elements</button>
<div id="userNumbers"></div>
```

If you have any questions please leave a comment below and I will reply as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!